# Why body match string in postman is passed even string iss not Exits in response?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, postman

Following I put in my test to check if ABC string exists or not.

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("ABC");
```

so, test pass as ABC was in response now I wanted to test fail so I check

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("ABC");
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("XYZ");
```

but still test pass, how?
and if I only check

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("XYZ");
```

then it fails.Strange.
Is there any way I can check or assert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tests["check ABC"] = responseBody.has("ABC");
tests["check XYZ"] = responseBody.has("XYZ");
```

This worked!!!